# Add If Statement to Code that Copies Using Column Headers

Tags: vba, excel

This code copies data from one worksheet to another using column headers.

But I need a condition so that it copies only the rows where column L matches the value of $AB$1. I just can't seem to get the syntax right, it's just ignoring my added if statement and is just copying everything.

EDIT to clarify...I'm looking to copy only the rows where L# = $AB$1.  Not copy all if L2 = AB1.  Make sense?

Any ideas?

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("CurrentPayrollNonExempt")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("BiWkly Template")

    With ws
        For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
            If (.Cells(2, "L").Value) = .Range("$AB$1").Value Then
                Set x = ws2.Rows(4).Find(ws.Cells(1, i).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not x Is Nothing Then
                    y = .Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(3).Row
                    .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(y, i)).Copy
                    ws2.Cells(5, x.Column).PasteSpecial xlValues
                End If

                Set x = Nothing
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your if seems fine. Have you tried to step through it with the debugger?

Comment: @litelite Double confirming here that the code above worked for me as well.

Comment: Works fine, however, since you never advance it inside the loop you can take the line `If (.Cells(2, "L").Value) = .Range("$AB$1").Value Then` and move it outside the `For` loop

Comment: Moving that line outside the For loop, it still does the same thing.  It's still not using the condition in the If statement, and it still copies all of the lines.

Comment: I think people are misinterpretting what you're trying to accomplish. If I understand you correctly, you don't want to check whether L2 = AB1, then copy. You want to copy the rows where L# = AB1.

Comment: @Mikegrann Yes! That's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: sorry for asking, what is `L#` ?

Comment: @Shai Rado  I'm using L# to mean any row in column L.

Comment: so are you looking for any cell inside Column L that equals cell $AB$1 ? it can be L2, L3 or L50 ?

Comment: @Shai Rado  Exactly!

Comment: Ok, so if it doesn't matter which row, why do you have it inside the `For` loop ?

Comment: @phelbin I hope I understood what you are looking for (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the minimal-edit version of what you want to do:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("CurrentPayrollNonExempt")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("BiWkly Template")

    With ws
        ' Filter out the rows to ignore
        .UsedRange.Autofilter 12, .Range("$AB$1").Value ' column 12 = "L"

        For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
            Set x = ws2.Rows(4).Find(ws.Cells(1, i).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not x Is Nothing Then
                y = .Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(3).Row
                .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(y, i)).Copy
                ws2.Cells(5, x.Column).PasteSpecial xlValues
            End If

            Set x = Nothing
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

It just hides the rows where column L is not equal to the desired value. Pretty sure everything else should work as expected.

Be careful using `UsedRange` (in my edit and your original). Depending on your worksheet this can go very poorly, as UsedRange might not be what you're expecting. Better if you looped through the columns like: `For i = 1 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlLeft).Column)` and if you filtered on your known table range like `.Range("A1:Z1000").Autofilter 'etc`.

Comment: I'd have to add a few steps, but it does work!  Thanks so much for your help.  At this point it's still plan B....but at least I know I can do it...thanks to you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

What is x and what is y? You never defined those. If you insert

```
Option Explicit
```

at the top of your module, it will force you to declare your variables.

I can't speak for everyone, but that seems like you're asking an awful lot out of a WITH statement. Personally, I would break that code up into more manageable and easier to read chunks, and your debugging will probably be easier to boot. There's no bonus points for condensing your code to the absolute minimum ;).

What is the data format of your spread sheets? Are you using tables? The table ListObject normally makes data handling a lot easier.

**EDIT:**
It appears you are only looping across all the columns in row 2, and you are never going down the rows. Add another control index, like this:

```
With ws
for j = 2 to .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        If (.Cells(j, "L").Value) = .Range("$AB$1").Value Then
            Set x = ws2.Rows(4).Find(ws.Cells(1, i).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not x Is Nothing Then
                y = .Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(3).Row
                .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(y, i)).Copy
                ws2.Cells(5, x.Column).PasteSpecial xlValues
            End If

            Set x = Nothing
        End If
    Next I
Next j
End With
```

The j loop should go down the rows, starting in row 2, and taking into account the end will be -1 due to the header row. The .Cells(j,"L") will thus be a constant value for each row pass.

Comment: They do are good advices, however they will not solve the current problem.

Comment: Tables are usually easier to work with, but the data is copied to a worksheet that gets uploaded to our accounting system.  So formatting changes aren't possible.  That's why I'm copying using column headers.

Comment: I've tried to break it up into chunks, but nothing has worked.  Any ideas?

Comment: Part of your problem might be that you are referring only to .Cell(2,"L") on each pass through all the used rows. In other words, the code loops through each column you used on ws1, looks at that cell and says "Nope, it's still the same as it was every other time, let's try the next one." Are you trying to get it to go down each row in the column?

Comment: @SandPiper that's exactly my problem.  What I want is for it to copy the rows where L# = $AB$1

Comment: @phelbin, Ok, I think I see your problem now then. See my edit above, and let me know if the extra control variable helped.

Comment: @SandPiper You're still copying the full column, including the rows where the condition is not met. All this accomplished is that now the code copies the *whole thing* a bunch of times (once for every valid row).

Comment: @phelbin, I am still not understanding what your intention is. Are you trying to copy all the data in row x from ws1 to ws2 if cell(x,"L") = cell("$AB$1")?

Comment: @SandPiper  Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.  And your code looks promising, but it's giving me a type mismatch for j and i if I do option explicit.  If I don't declare the variables, then it still copies everything...not just the rows where L# = $AB$1.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you want, since you are not advancing your search criteria, I took it outside the `For` loop.

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("CurrentPayrollNonExempt")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("BiWkly Template")

    With ws
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Range("$AB$1").Value, .Columns("L:L"), 0)) Then
            For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
                Set x = ws2.Rows(4).Find(ws.Cells(1, i).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not x Is Nothing Then
                    y = .Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(3).Row
                    .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(y, i)).Copy
                    ws2.Cells(5, x.Column).PasteSpecial xlValues
                End If

                Set x = Nothing
            Next i

        Else
            ' for debug purposes only
            MsgBox "Value in Cell $AB$1 not found"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```